# Plug-in that shows x number thumbnails from another post

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, gallery

I am building a blog where the posts of  a certain category make up image galleries (using the standard WP functionality and a modified  single.php to display the gallery.)

Now, I would like to add links to some of those galleries inside other blog posts. The ideal way would be a shortcode like

```
[thumbnails galleryid=209]
```

(or whatever) that displays a definable number of thumbnails from post no. 209, and links there.

Does anybody know of a ready-made plugin that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, but you could use [get_children](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) and get the attachment(s) of those posts:

```
$attachments = get_children(array(
  'post_parent'     => $post->ID, // <- source post
  'post_status'     => 'inherit',
  'post_type'       => 'attachment',
  'post_mime_type'  => 'image',
  'order'           => 'post_date',
  'orderby'         => 'DESC',
  'numberposts'     => 5,         // the number
));
```

Then get the image URLs:

```
$size = 'post-thumbnail'; // or whatever size you need

foreach($attachments as $att){
  list($source, $width, $height) = wp_get_attachment_image_src($att->ID, $size); 
  // echo '<img src="'.$source.'" width="'.$width.'" height='".$height."' />';
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! This worked, and in conjunction with a [custom short tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) does exactly what I need.